# How do I call the standard New Note or New Attachment pages?

Tags: apex, visualforce, attachment, notes

I have a requirement where I need to provide New Note and New Attachment buttons on a Visualforce page and cannot use the standard related list. Every method I've tried so far has led to an error:

- Using `URLFOR($Action.Note.New)`, but that `$Action` [does not exist](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_global_action_valid_values.htm).
- A direct link to `/002/e?parent_id=[record id]`, but that gives a "Data Not Available" error message (tried with and without confirmation token)
- Using an `<apex:commandButton>` where the following controller method provides a redirect also yields "Data Not Available":

  ```
  public PageReference NewNote(){
    PageReference redirect = new PageReference('/002/e');
    redirect.getParameters().put('parent_id', sfObject.Id);
    redirect.getParameters().put('retURL', this.ReturnUrl);
    redirect.setRedirect(true);
    return redirect;
  }
  ```

Is there any way to invoke the pages for New Note and New Attachments without using the standard related list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Note case, `/002/e?parent_id=[record id]` doesn't work for me with the 18 digit id (Data Not Available) but **does with the 15 digit id**.

For the Attachment case, `/p/attach/NoteAttach?pid=[record id]&retURL=...` works, though as an even less "documented" URL pattern you may not want to risk it. 15 digit id again.

Comment: I'll have to try out the 15 digit id; that never even occurred to since I thought they were interchangeable.

Comment: So both of these work; thank you. I'm going to give it a day or two to see if there is a more official or sanctioned method before marking it as the answer, though.

Comment: Makes sense. If there is a cleaner way I'll change my code to use that too.

Comment: Salesforce support suggested (and linked to) this answer. "I would like to inform as the Note object is not supported for $Action variable. Please use the sample code mentioned on the link below:
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/31766/142

This is only the way by which we can create the Note record."

Comment: does this still work (the 15 char parentId) for Notes?  I can't make it work - Data Not Available

Comment: @crop1645 Just tried it in a Winter '16 org and still worked for me.

Comment: weird, in spring 16 org, following VF generates "data Not Available" `<apex:commandButton value="New Note" action="/002/e?parent_id=a1pJ0000003J6Dr"/>` - Note I even tried with hardcoded ID - don't tell anyone :-)

Comment: @crop1645 Just checked in a Spring '16 org and the pattern still seems to work done manually in the URL and in some JavaScript. I would have expected your action attribute to reference a controller method rather than have the URL directly there.